# Shopify if statement in for loop

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have some variants I'm looping over and then assigning the whole thing to a variable

```
   {% if settings.limit_quantity or settings.display_inventory_left %}
      {% assign variantInventory = data-variant-inventory:'[
       {% for v in product.variants %}
         {
           "id":{{ v.id }},
           "inventory_quantity":{{v.inventory_quantity}},
           "inventory_management":"{{- v.inventory_management -}}",
           "inventory_policy":"{{ v.inventory_policy }}"
         }
         {% if forloop.last == false %},{% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
    ]'%}
  {% endif %}
```

This is then put onto the form as an attribute

```
   {% form 'product', product, id: "product-form-{{ product.id }}", class: "clearfix product_form init {{cssClass}}", variantInventory, data-product-id:"{{ product.id }}"%}
```

But I'm getting error Liquid syntax error (line 21): 'endfor' is not a valid delimiter for if tags. use endif

Comment: you can't initialize the array in shopify liquid.

Comment: @Developer can you show me where it’s wrong and what it should be?

Comment: I don't know what are you trying to do with this. I think you are new to this. The liquid templating language is very different. So, the way you are assigning the array to a variable is not possible in shopify liquid. Read the following link and go to Initializing arrays heading. https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/types/#array

Comment: @Developer I’m looping over product variants and assigning them to a variable which will be added as an attribute to the form. Yeah I’m new to this. Can you provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that you are thinking about it like it's JavaScript.

First things first:

1. You can't run an assign and a forloop at the same time. You can do things like:
   `assign myVar = 'hello world' | replace: 'world', ''` But that's it. You can read more about pipelines here:
   https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/filters
2. You can't create arrays in liquid that way. They can be created but it's tricky:
   `assign myArray = 'apple,orange,strawberry' | split: ','`. Now you will be able to iterate over your "Array".

So to answer your question:

```
{% if settings.limit_quantity or settings.display_inventory_left %}
  {% assign variantInventory = "" %}
  {% for v in product.variants %}
    {% capture variant %}
      {
        "id": {{ v.id }},
        "inventory_quantity": {{ v.inventory_quantity }},
        "inventory_management": "{{ v.inventory_management }}",
        "inventory_policy": "{{ v.inventory_policy }}"
      }{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
    {% endcapture %}
    {% assign variantInventory = variantInventory | append: variant %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Once you have the variantInventory variable assigned, you can proceed to use it in your form attribute or any other required context.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (not tested):

```
   {%- if settings.limit_quantity or settings.display_inventory_left -%}
      {%- capture variantInventory -%}
       data-variant-inventory:'[
       {%- for v in product.variants -%}
         {
           "id":{{ v.id }},
           "inventory_quantity":{{v.inventory_quantity}},
           "inventory_management":"{{- v.inventory_management -}}",
           "inventory_policy":"{{ v.inventory_policy }}"
         }
         {%- unless forloop.last -%},{%- endunless -%}
       {%- endfor -%}
       ]'
     {%- endcapture -%}
  {%- endif -%}
```

Then you may use it in your form:

```
<form data-variant-inventory="{{ variantInventory }}"></form>
```

HTH